# Abstracting a loop

Tags: recursion, f#

I find myself writing loops (recursive functions) occasionally within assignments. It makes for awkward code like this:

```
let value =
  let rec loop a =
    if ... then a
    else loop a.B
  loop a
```

I know I could move the loop outside the `let` binding, but it's only purpose is to compute the bound value.

So I thought I might abstract the loop into a separate function:

```
let loop f a =
  let rec aux a =
    match f a with
    | Some b -> aux b
    | None -> a
  aux a
```

then I could do:

```
let value = a |> loop (fun a -> if ... then None else Some a.B)
```

Maybe that's better--at least it looks like more like assignment than a function definition. Here are my questions:

1. Is a recursive function in a `let` binding something of a code smell?
2. Is there a better way to refactor this?
3. If not, could my `loop` function be generalized further, or somehow improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These questions are a bit subjective, but here are my answers:

1. No
2. I think what you've got is okay.
3. Here's how I'd do it:

   ```
   let rec loop guard step init =
       if guard init then init
       else loop guard step (step init)

   let value = a |> loop (fun a -> ...) (fun a -> a.B)
   ```

Comment: Ha. Once you generalize it further you practically end up where you started.

Comment: I was having a hard time imagining the compiled representation (.NET Reflector crashes on F# code). I was able to check it with ILSpy though. I should have guessed it moves the loop to a separate function, leaving only a function call at the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your or kvb's solutions are perfectly fine.

I don't know what is the data structure that you're iterating over in the loop. It looks like a data structure though, so it may make sense to implement the `IEnuemerable<'T>` interface or write a function that turns it into `IEnumerable<'T>`:

```
let rec asSeq a = seq {
  yield a 
  yield! asSeq a.B }
```

Then you could just use `Seq.find` and give it the condition you need:

```
// Using explicit conversion function
let value = a |> asSeq |> Seq.find (fun a -> ...)

// If 'a' actually implements 'seq<'T>', it is even nicer:
let value = a |> Seq.find (fun a -> ...)
```

Comment: It's an object graph so, yes, it would be possible to turn it into a sequence, although it would seem overkill. I was hoping to figure out a way to make this more concise.